# Barcode 128 not reading when is inside a table cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I'm able to create barcodes inside a table cell but the problem is that they are not readable. If I add a barcode outside the table is readable/scannable.

I think the problem is that the cells borders may be affecting readability but I can't figure out how to fix this.

Here is my code that I use to add to a cell.

```
code128.CodeType = Barcode.CODE128;
                    code128.Code = r[2].ToString().Trim();

                    iTextSharp.text.Image image128 = code128.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);
                    // Add image to table cell
                    table.AddCell(image128);
```

it prints on the PDF but not readable by the barcode scanner.

the code below adds a standalone to the document and is readable by the barcode scanner.

```
 Barcode128 code128 = new Barcode128();
        code128.CodeType = Barcode.CODE128;
        code128.Code = "123456";
        iTextSharp.text.Image image128 = code128.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null);

        // Add image to table cell
        document.Add(image128);
```

I have tried playing with the columns widths but no luck.

Comment: is the full barcode printing, or is it clipping?  You might just need padding.

Comment: Note than most barcodes require a [quiet zone](https://barcode.com/201303251124/bar-code-quiet-zones-illustrated-and-explained.html) surrounding them with no graphics, text, chrome, or anything in order to be usable.

Comment: Thanks. I added some padding so the border is not too close. Is reading now. thanks all